# Subtract multiple values returned by SQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table `transaction` which has columns `amount`, `date` and `type`, type is an id field which belongs to choice `earning`, `expenses`, let's say id=1 is earning and id=2 is expenses.

I want to get monthly savings by:

```
savings = earning - expenses
```

I can get all the transactions separately by:

```
select amount from transaction where id='1'  -- will give earnings
select amount from transaction where id='2'  -- will give expenses
```

These two queries returns multiple results, because there might be many transactions of earning and expenses.

I got total savings by:

```
select (select SUM(transaction.amount) from transaction where id='1') - 
(select SUM(transaction.amount) from transaction where id='2') as savings;
```

**BUT**

I want to subtract `transaction.amount` from *earning query result* and *expenses query result* and **group them by** month so I'll have monthly savings.

How do I subtract two query results which returns multiple values and group them by date?

I'm using PostgreSQL

Comment: which db are you using? why did you tag mysql?

Comment: If possible, why don't you change your table design?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that in a single query:

```
select date_trunc('month', "date") as month, 
       SUM(transaction.amount) filter (where id = 1) 
        - 
       SUM(transaction.amount) filter (where id = 2) as savings
from transaction 
group by date_trunc('month', "date");
```

Answer (score 1):

intuitively I would tell you to try a solution like this:

```
SELECT tot_expense-tot_saving, tot_expense, tot_saving, month
FROM (select SUM(transaction.amount) tot_expense, month from transaction where 
id='1' group by month) as amount
LEFT JOIN (select SUM(transaction.amount) tot_saving, month from transaction 
WHERE id='2' group by month) as savings ON amount.month=savings.month
```

I'll put all field in SELECT for a control check.
(Edit: forgot group by in the second select)